# How to create a golang hot folder to modify files only once

Tags: file, go

I have a situation where a program is outputting a file. There is one line of text that I must alter in order to fix the file. I do not own the source code for the program so I must alter every file that this program spits out so it can be correctly used by another program.

Because of the nature of the process, I cannot rename the files or move them.

Therefore, I want to see any new file dropped in (easy enough with a loop and sleep) and alter the file but only do this once as other processes will need to come along and use this file.

I have written many similar applications in Go but was always allowed to move the files.

Comment: You can write a filter to change the text in the file while writing to another file, then remove the original and move the modified file in place of the deleted file. Is that acceptable? What kind of modification do you have to do in the file? If the resulting text is the same length or less than the original, you might be able to do it in place as well. If it can be larger, not so easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code I came up with: Open to suggestions on how to do this in place with a Seeker as I am only deleting a single line of text in the file.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"       
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "strings"
)

const dir = "dir00003"

func main() {

fmt.Println("Running...")

//Go into a loop forever
for {

    //Wait 60 seconds before taking any action. 
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
    //Read all of the file data for all files in the directory: 
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {fmt.Println("Failed to read transfer folder. There must be a folder named `dir00003`!"); continue}

    for _, v := range files {

        //if this is an index file, skip over it as we don't care: 
        if strings.Contains(v.Name(), "pmi") {continue}

        //if the file was created within the last 2 minutes, we should check if we need to modify it
        if time.Now().Sub(v.ModTime()) < (time.Minute * 2) {

            //open the file 
            f, err := os.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))
            if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tCouldn't open file: %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

            defer f.Close()
            //read all of the bytes of the file
            bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
            if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tCouldn't read bytes from %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

            //see if the <program_parameters/> tag is in the file
            b := bytes.Contains(bs, []byte("<program_parameters/>"))

            //if the tag is in the file, we should replace it, otherwise we move on to the next file
            if b {
                //replace the tag with nothing. Only look for the first instance and then abort the process of replacing.
                rbs := bytes.Replace(bs, []byte("<program_parameters/>"), []byte(""), 1)
                //close the file so we can delete it. 
                f.Close()
                //delete the exisint file. 
                os.Remove(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))

                //create a new file with the same original name:
                nf, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", dir, v.Name()))
                if err != nil {fmt.Printf("\tFailed to create new file for %s\n", v.Name()); continue}

                //write all of the bytes that we have in memory to our new file. 
                _, err = nf.Write(rbs)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println("Failed to write to new file %s\n", v.Name()); continue}
                //close our new file
                nf.Close()

                fmt.Printf("Modified new file: %s", v.Name())

            } else {
                continue
            }

        }

    

    }

    fmt.Printf("\nDone with round\n")

}

fmt.Println("PROGRAM STOPPED RUNNING!!")

return 
}
```